# Regex: Everything before a word

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text:

```
There are 12.800.500 sorts of animals.
```

Now, I want to get 12.800.800 as the output, when I search for "sorts". How could I do that? I tried

```
\d+(?= sorts)
```

but this gives me only "500" as a result and not the whole number with dots.
How can I make sure I get "everything" before "sorts" until the first space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you're trying to match also includes DOTS not just digits so use this regex:

```
\b[\d.]+(?=\s+sorts)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lC2eL1/2)

`[\d.]` will match either a digit or a DOT.

To match any non-space character use:

```
\S+(?=\s+sorts)
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way to make that "general" so that would also work for commas and so on by having the regex go back until the "first space" basically viewing "12.800.500" as a word?